# Python: Replace a number in array with a string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of numbers, which I would like to replace with a string depending on some condition. I can replace them with numbers:

```
d_sex = rand(10)
d_sex[d_sex > 0.5] = 1
d_sex[d_sex <= 0.5] = 0
d_sex
```

But I cannot do `d_sex[d_sex>0.5] = "F"`. How would I do that in the most pythonic way? Would I create an empty string array? I am looking for something similar to Julia's:

```
d_sex = rand(50)
s_sex = ifelse(d_sex .> 0.5, "M", "F")
[d_sex s_sex]
```

Comment: Are you talking about `numpy` arrays?

Comment: I think map would be appropriate

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: If you're trying to generate random zeros and ones you can use: 
`d_sex = int(random.random()  + 0.5)`. If that's not what you're looking for try adding more details to your question

Comment: If you want to mix data types, consider a pandas DataFrame. You can have a numpy string (or object) array, but it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is the equivalent of Julia's `ifelse`:

```
>>> np.where(d_sex > 0.5, 'M', 'F')
array(['F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F'], 
  dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use numpy then map is probably the best thing to do

```
a = [random() for _ in range(10)]
map(lambda x: 'F' if x > .5 else 'M', a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `dtype` as `object` and it will allow you to replace `float` with a `string` as:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d_sex = np.random.rand(10).astype('object')
>>> d_sex
array([0.6481844853562397, 0.1369951687351887, 0.4672729496950908,
       0.10511352546752228, 0.3967990781535288, 0.3452032518851482,
       0.34527110292775176, 0.24858258988637605, 0.2890001412667411,
       0.9504476492941463], dtype=object)
>>> d_sex[d_sex>0.5] = 'F'
>>> d_sex[d_sex<=0.5] = 'M'
>>> d_sex
array(['F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comperhension

```
a = [0, 1, 0]
b = ['F' if i > 0.5 else 'M' for i in a]

=> ['M', 'F', 'M']
```